# JAVA_HOME error while 'play run' on Windows -- play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I am getting error while doing 'play run'

"Could not execute the Java executable, please make sure the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set properly (the Java executable should reside at JAVA_HOME/bin/java)."

But I can confirm that , `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly, as I am able to run 'java' command from console i.e. DOS prompt.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: "D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23"

Answer (score 3):

Set user variable
JAVA_HOME to C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

and

extend the system variable
Path with %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

works for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 7. `echo %JAVA_HOME%` returned `C:\Programmes\Java\jdk1.7.0`, which seemed correct. However, in Windows 7, even though path looks like that in explorer, the "real" path to use with `cmd` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`.

I updated `JAVA_HOME` and restarted `cmd` — otherwise, the terminal wouldn't refresh its variables — and it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to run java from your command line does NOT indicate that you have set the JAVA_HOME variable. Do you know how to do that?? Or do you know how to check if this variable exist?

Here is a quick way IF you are using Windows: Right click My Computer (or Computer in Windows 7) then click the tab Advanced then environment variables. In the System variables check if there is an entry with the variable JAVA_HOME. If NOT create one (by clicking new) giving JAVA_HOME in variable name and the path of your jdk in the variable value. IF let's say, your jdk is installed on the following path: c:\jdk6 in your pc THEN this should be your variable value. Click Ok, Ok again and then run your app again!

Comment: Yes , I do have that. It is in 'System Variables' section pointing to "D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23"

Comment: Not sure if this will help but how about using backslashes instead of slashes, this means in your case D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23 . And one final think, in case of jboss at least the version 4.2 the installation of jdk should be in a path with folders names containing NO space (meaning if jdk was installed in Program Files it didn't work). Don't know if this would help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done `echo %JAVA_HOME%`?

Several issues:

- `JAVA_HOME` (a variable used by the JVM) is not the same than `PATH` (a variable used by the OS to locate directories where to find executables). Doing `java.exe` just shows that the bin directory of Java is in PATH, not that JAVA_HOME points where it should (or even it exists)
- Also, Windows usually does not use the `PATH` variable, but instead treats java specially and stores its location in the register (do an `echo %PATH%` to check this).

In conclussion: You cannot assume `JAVA_HOME` is set; check for it directly and set it (Control Panel-> System -> Advanced).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a DOS-Path in JAVA-Home. Meaning no fakes from Win-7 C:\Programme in real C:\Program Files and no blank in path.

```
C:\>dir /x Prog*

09.08.2011  13:55    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
21.08.2011  20:25    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

This is a safe solution.

echo %JAVA_HOME% is indeed always a good idea to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64 bit Windows version, make sure you have both the 32bit and 64bit version of Java installed (so there must be a Java directory in both Program Files and Program Files (x86). That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my `jdk` from `1.6.0_14` to `1.7.0_10` and my `jre6` to `jre7` and had the same problem on XP. 
I then deleted `JAVA_HOME` and added it again and it worked.
I also added `JRE_HOME` as a System Variable

```
JAVA_HOME --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
JRE_HOME --> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably overdated here, but in my case, I had to edit the `play.bat` and set JAVA_HOME path:

```
@echo off
set "JAVA_HOME=JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8"
"%~dp0python\python.exe" "%~dp0play" %*
```

Hope it helps.